# How to add Wildfly RTS subsystem via JBoss CLI commands?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, command-line-interface, wildfly, jboss-cli

I am trying to add the RTS subsystem, for the moment with the default values. If I do it within standalone.xml it is fairly simple, I just have to add the extension and the subsystem to the appropriate sections:

```
<extensions>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.rts"/>
</extensions>

<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:rts:1.0">
        <servlet server="default-server" host="default-host" socket-binding="http"/>
    </subsystem>
</profile>
```

However when I try to do the same via the CLI, it fails with a nondescript error message. When I execute the following batch:

```
/extension=org.wildfly.extension.rts/:add
/subsystem=rts/:add(server=default-server, host=default-host, socket-binding=http)
```

I get this error which supposedly signals configuration errors:

```
#0 2.831 org.jboss.as.cli.CommandFormatException: Failed to get the list of the operation properties: "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [("subsystem" => "rts")]": Failed to get the list of the operation properties: "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [("subsystem" => "rts")]"
```

Any idea what is the problem? And ultimately I want to change the host name to document_service, how can I do that?

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using? Where do you see this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload your server after adding the extension